# Unable to create Json to pojo in Model class

Tags: android, json, pojo

```
   [ {
        "asin": "B01CYB01YM",
        "categories": [
            "59d24dddc3d7130100260e45"
        ],
        "locale": "en_IN",
        "tags": [
            "string"
        ],
        "lastSyncSuccess": true,
        "productDetails": [
            {
                "ASIN": [
                    "B01CYB01YM"
                ],
                "DetailPageURL": [
                    "https://www.amazon.in/Princeware-Store-Fresh-Plastic-Bowl/dp/B01CYB01YM?SubscriptionId=AKIAJOXABSYIMSYRFD3Q&tag=derrickpaulch-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B01CYB01YM"
                ],
                "ItemLinks": [
                    {
                        "ItemLink": [
                            {
                                "Description": [
                                    "Add To Wishlist"
                                ],
                                "URL": [
                                    "https://www.amazon.in/gp/registry/wishlist/add-item.html?asin.0=B01CYB01YM&SubscriptionId=AKIAJOXABSYIMSYRFD3Q&tag=derrickpaulch-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B01CYB01YM"
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "Description": [
                                    "Tell A Friend"
                                ],
                                "URL": [
                                    "https://www.amazon.in/gp/pdp/taf/B01CYB01YM?SubscriptionId=AKIAJOXABSYIMSYRFD3Q&tag=derrickpaulch-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B01CYB01YM"
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "Description": [
                                    "All Customer Reviews"
                                ],
                                "URL": [
                                    "https://www.amazon.in/review/product/B01CYB01YM?SubscriptionId=AKIAJOXABSYIMSYRFD3Q&tag=derrickpaulch-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B01CYB01YM"
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "Description": [
                                    "All Offers"
                                ],
                                "URL": [
                                    "https://www.amazon.in/gp/offer-listing/B01CYB01YM?SubscriptionId=AKIAJOXABSYIMSYRFD3Q&tag=derrickpaulch-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B01CYB01YM"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],

                "ItemAttributes": [
                    {
                        "Brand": [
                            "Princeware"
                        ],
                        "Color": [
                            "Green"
                        ],
                        "EAN": [
                            "0728632342267"
                        ],
                        "EANList": [
                            {
                                "EANListElement": [
                                    "0728632342267"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "Feature": [
                            "PRINCEWARE"
                        ],
                        "ItemDimensions": [
                            {
                                "Weight": [
                                    {
                                        "_": "104",
                                        "ref": "",
                                        "036": {
                                            "Units": "hundredths-pounds"
                                        },
                                        "name": ""
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "Label": [
                            "808349545554"
                        ],
                        "ListPrice": [
                            {
                                "Amount": [
                                    "30100"
                                ],
                                "CurrencyCode": [
                                    "INR"
                                ],
                                "FormattedPrice": [
                                    "INR 301.00"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "Manufacturer": [
                            "808349545554"
                        ],
                        "Model": [
                            "Princeware Store Fresh Plastic Bowl 5pcs"
                        ],
                        "MPN": [
                            "Princeware store"
                        ],
                        "PackageDimensions": [
                            {
                                "Height": [
                                    {
                                        "_": "394",
                                        "ref": "",
                                        "036": {
                                            "Units": "hundredths-inches"
                                        },
                                        "name": ""
                                    }
                                ],
                                "Length": [
                                    {
                                        "_": "736",
                                        "ref": "",
                                        "036": {
                                            "Units": "hundredths-inches"
                                        },
                                        "name": ""
                                    }
                                ],
                                "Weight": [
                                    {
                                        "_": "75",
                                        "ref": "",
                                        "036": {
                                            "Units": "hundredths-pounds"
                                        },
                                        "name": ""
                                    }
                                ],
                                "Width": [
                                    {
                                        "_": "713",
                                        "ref": "",
                                        "036": {
                                            "Units": "hundredths-inches"
                                        },
                                        "name": ""
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "PackageQuantity": [
                            "1"
                        ],
                        "PartNumber": [
                            "Princeware store"
                        ],
                        "ProductGroup": [
                            "Kitchen"
                        ],
                        "ProductTypeName": [
                            "KITCHEN"
                        ],
                        "Publisher": [
                            "808349545554"
                        ],
                        "Size": [
                            "set of 5"
                        ],
                        "Studio": [
                            "808349545554"
                        ],
                        "Title": [
                            "Princeware"
                        ],
                        "UPC": [
                            "728632342267"
                        ],
                        "UPCList": [
                            {
                                "UPCListElement": [
                                    "728632342267"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "OfferSummary": [
                    {
                        "LowestNewPrice": [
                            {
                                "Amount": [
                                    "24900"
                                ],
                                "CurrencyCode": [
                                    "INR"
                                ],
                                "FormattedPrice": [
                                    "INR 249.00"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "TotalNew": [
                            "3"
                        ],
                        "TotalUsed": [
                            "0"
                        ],
                        "TotalCollectible": [
                            "0"
                        ],
                        "TotalRefurbished": [
                            "0"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "Offers": [
                    {
                        "TotalOffers": [
                            "1"
                        ],
                        "TotalOfferPages": [
                            "1"
                        ],
                        "MoreOffersUrl": [
                            "https://www.amazon.in/gp/offer-listing/B01CYB01YM?SubscriptionId=AKIAJOXABSYIMSYRFD3Q&tag=derrickpaulch-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B01CYB01YM"
                        ],
                        "Offer": [
                            {
                                "OfferAttributes": [
                                    {
                                        "Condition": [
                                            "New"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "OfferListing": [
                                    {
                                        "OfferListingId": [
                                            "6thY%2FLAkJOK4TeD5BZNHisq2zTb6eCDO4dXRDGLm5UunnE0CcFmEuEz2RXZVJUxeb1noHkUTpGAgSmJgfLwEwoRI%2BnBP1c5tihkvQUbEos5KOnaRKXEH2sVIWJ4N5Z1w9deLUG4J3ovRGzg9gjJYcccUdpyiBkXC"
                                        ],
                                        "Price": [
                                            {
                                                "Amount": [
                                                    "29900"
                                                ],
                                                "CurrencyCode": [
                                                    "INR"
                                                ],
                                                "FormattedPrice": [
                                                    "INR 299.00"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "SalePrice": [
                                            {
                                                "Amount": [
                                                    "24900"
                                                ],
                                                "CurrencyCode": [
                                                    "INR"
                                                ],
                                                "FormattedPrice": [
                                                    "INR 249.00"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "AmountSaved": [
                                            {
                                                "Amount": [
                                                    "5000"
                                                ],
                                                "CurrencyCode": [
                                                    "INR"
                                                ],
                                                "FormattedPrice": [
                                                    "INR 50.00"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "PercentageSaved": [
                                            "17"
                                        ],
                                        "Availability": [
                                            "Usually dispatched within 1-2 business days"
                                        ],
                                        "AvailabilityAttributes": [
                                            {
                                                "AvailabilityType": [
                                                    "now"
                                                ],
                                                "MinimumHours": [
                                                    "24"
                                                ],
                                                "MaximumHours": [
                                                    "48"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping": [
                                            "0"
                                        ],
                                        "IsEligibleForPrime": [
                                            "0"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "createdAt": "2017-10-07T13:38:30.440Z",
        "updatedAt": "2017-10-07T13:38:30.440Z",
        "id": "59d8d8d61c79080100065266"
    }



]
```

This is my Json i am trying to convert it in Pojo using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/  but there is Error is coming There's a problem: Internal server error :(  i dont know what i am doing mistake while given Json is valid Json. please suggest me what i am doing wrong .

[image]

Comment: that is a server error on the site. What we can do in that. You can try some other sites

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is problem of the website that you are using not related to android

Comment: Try this plugin https://github.com/zzz40500/GsonFormat

Comment: Use this site pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/

Comment: you should try using different sites this is not a valid question

Comment: Use some other tool as others mentioned or if you are hell bent to use this tool, ask this question on their [github issue](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/issues/new) page and someone will help you out.

Comment: use this  http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/

Comment: problem with another that  how create 036 class that i am unable to create

Comment: 036  unable to  generate class @VivekMishra